# How do i check the state of bind() function in tkinter? (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

The goal of the program was to create a never-ending game of clicking the button. Every time the mouse pointer hovered over the button `btn`, it would move randomly across the window. But I can't seem to get the status of when the mouse hovers over the button. pardon any mistakes and feel free to correct them, I'm just a beginner. Heres the code -

```
from tkinter import *
import time
import random

window = Tk()
window.geometry("500x500")

lbl = Label(window, text = "Try to click the button")
lbl.pack()

def move_btn():
    global btn
    if btn.bind("<Enter>") == True:
        wi = random.randint(0, 500)
        hi = random.randint(0, 500)
        btn.place(x = hi, y = wi)

btn = Button(window, text = "Click ME!",command = move_btn)
btn.pack()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Just remove `if btn.bind(...)` from `move_btn()` and call `btn.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: move_btn())` after creating `btn`.  Is it what you want?

Comment: @acw1668 thanks! Let me go futher into this to analyze what you've just writtem but it worked! :)